# json conversion in array python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I need to convert this json excerpt using python language transforming **list** into an array.
What is the best practice or any smart method to do that?

```
{
  "date": "2020-10-19",
  "aaa": "123",
  "bbb": "456",
  "ccc": "description",
  "list": {
    "cap": {
      "path": "data0",
    },
    "ope": {
      "path": "data1",
    },
    "tri": {
      "path": "data2",
    }
  }
}
```

into this

```
{
  "date": "2020-10-19",
  "aaa": "123",
  "bbb": "456",
  "ccc": "description",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "cap",
      "path": "data0"
    },
    {
      "name": "ope",
      "path": "data1"
    },
    {
      "name": "tri",
      "path": "data2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
l = {
  "date": "2020-10-19",
  "aaa": "123",
  "bbb": "456",
  "ccc": "description",
  "list": {
    "cap": {
      "path": "data0",
    },
    "ope": {
      "path": "data1",
    },
    "tri": {
      "path": "data2",
    }
  }
}

new_list = []
for k, v in l['list'].items():
    v['name'] = k
    new_list.append(v)

l['list'] = new_list
print(l)
```

Comment: This is the best because is independend from the content of the json. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
input["list"] = [{"name":key, "path":value["path"]} for key,value in input["list"].items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do it

```
d = {
  "date": "2020-10-19",
  "aaa": "123",
  "bbb": "456",
  "ccc": "description",
  "list": {
    "cap": {
      "path": "data0",
    },
    "ope": {
      "path": "data1",
    },
    "tri": {
      "path": "data2",
    }
  }
}
d["list"] = [{'name':k,'path':v['path']} for k,v in d["list"].items()]
```